# dual booting on separate disks

Tags: dual-boot

I am dual booting Kubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 on a desktop with an SSD and a hard disk. The PC came with windows 10 on the SSD and I installed Kubuntu on the hard disk with out disconnecting the SSD. Grub grabbed control of Kubuntu and the SSD. My intent was to keep the two disk devices separate and select my boot device from the PC BIOS. Can I safely, without reinstalling, do this?

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives? Do you have an ESP - efi system partition on HDD, or only on SSD? Post this in question above: `lsblk -f`  If you have an ESP on HDD, you can just update fstab with that drive's ESP & reinstall grub. See this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Got the system working the way I want by adding "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true" to Grub.

Comment: You can tell if Ubuntu boots from Windows' ESP by checking which ESP by GUID/partUUID is used. `sudo efibootmgr -v ` & 
`lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`
Check partUUIDs match to ESP - efi system partition(s) you have.